# Linq2Sql and lambda returns "Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL"

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Why does...

```
Func<IQueryable<CampaignCodePaths>> table = () => CampaignCodePaths;

Func<CampaignCodePaths, int> propertySelector = e => e.Id;

int key = 1;

Func<CampaignCodePaths, bool> whereSelector = e => propertySelector(e).Equals(key);

table().Where(whereSelector).FirstOrDefault();
```

...work but...

```
Func<IQueryable<CampaignCodePaths>> table = () => CampaignCodePaths;

Func<CampaignCodePaths, int> propertySelector = e => e.Id;

int key = 1;

table().Where(e => propertySelector(e).Equals(key)).FirstOrDefault();
```

...returns exception:

> Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL

?

UPDATE

To clarify:

```
CampaignCodePath Get(Func<IQueryable<CampaignCodePaths>> table, Func<CampaignCodePaths, int> selector, int key)
{
    return table().Where(/*How to I create this expression from selector and key? */).FirstOrDefault();
}

...

Get(() => CampaignCodePaths, e => e.Id, 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first piece of code is performing all the filtering in .NET because you're using a delegate instead of an expression tree - it's not even *trying* to convert the filter into SQL. In other words, it's not that the first "works" and the second doesn't - it's that the first doesn't fail because it doesn't really try to do what you're expecting, whereas the second does.

The second form is calling `Queryable.Where(IQueryable<T>, Expression<...>)` whereas the first is calling `Enumerable.Where(IEnumerable<T>, Func<...>)`.

If you change your code to:

```
Expression<Func<CampaignCodePaths, bool>> filter = e => e.Id.Equals(key);
table().Where(filter).FirstOrDefault();
```

then it should be fine.

EDIT: Responding to your edit, I think you want something like:

```
CampaignCodePath Get(Func<IQueryable<CampaignCodePaths>> table,
                     Expression<Func<CampaignCodePaths, int> selector>,
                     int key)
{
    Expression equal = Expression.Equal(selector, Expression.Constant(key));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Expression<Func<CampaignCodePaths, bool>>
        (equal, selector.Parameters);
    return table().Where(lambda).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for spotting that! Can you please explain how I can use Expression instead?

Comment: @Niels: Have updated the answer slightly - you should be able to just drop that in.

Comment: Only problem is that filter is defined somewhere else. The key is need to "bound" to filer dynamically. Is is possible to do some curry magic?

Comment: @Niels: You probably want to use the expression API, e.g. `Expression.Equal(filter, Expression.Constant(key))` and then use `Expression.Lambda` to get an appropriate final type. If you could provide more context in the question we can probably help more, if that's not enough.

Comment: How do I combine the selector with the key to get the Where?

Would like to do something like:
Expression<Func<CampaignCodePaths, int>> selector = e => e.Id;

//...

int key = 1;
table().Where(Expression.Equal(selector, Expression.Constant(key))).FirstOrDefault().Dump();

Comment: @Niels: It would be better if you could edit the question with the extra context rather than putting it in comments. Show all the information you have at the various different bits, so we can tell what we need to build.

Comment: I've updated my previous post. Would appreciate if you can help me. I'm stuck :(

Comment: @Niels: I've edited my answer, but I don't have access to MSDN right now, so there may be a few typos. See if it helps.